# $(...).draggable is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have got this code:

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
    var potv = $("#FUWTEHOHS").position().top;
    var spotv = $("#FUWTEHOHS").position().left;
    $("#TTFTGTHIWW").css("top", potv + 50).css("left", spotv + 450);
    $(function() {
        $("#TTFTGTHIWW").draggable();
    });  
});
```

```css
#TTFTGTHIWW {
    background: black;
    border: 1px dashed white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

```html
<div id="TTFTGTHIWW"></div>
```

But it is not working it gives an error:

> $(...).draggable is not a function

Comment: The `draggable()` method is part of jQueryUI. You need to include that library *as well* as jQuery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have got this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

Comment: That's the CSS, you need to inlcude the JS file too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh okay

Comment: Also note that you can provide the `css()` method with an object containing multiple properties to reduce calls, and also the `draggable()` instatiation doesn't need to be in its own DOMReady handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i downloaded 2 jquery ui js files but it is not working

Comment: Element with the id #FUWTEHOHS is missing. When I added that to the code its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/9dx1cxu8/14/

Comment: @RinoRaj i have got that element

Comment: did you add jquery ui ATER jquery? also, do you get any errors in the dev console?

Comment: Then please see the fiddle. Its working fine. Check if jquery-ui.js is included. Also please check the order in which you have included the js files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the JQuery library in your script.